# PDO mysql query not working

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

For some reason this query isnt working. It isnt throwing any errors. if i use it in the traditional mysqli. it works.. im trying to convert my sql to pdo.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'root', 'root');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$user_id = is_numeric($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : die();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from posts WHERE user_id=:user_id ");
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$i=1;
if ($i=1) {
foreach ($rows as $row) {
if (($row["user_id"])==true){
echo $row["title"];
}  
}
```

Comment: `$i=1;if ($i=1)` wtf? Redundant check and wrong operator

Comment: i had a row count statement.. didnt know if that was the problem so i removed that :D

Comment: You also have another redundant check around `($row["user_id"])==true`.

Comment: had ' if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {' before .. so yeh.. iwe never used pdo.. so i was trying to get rid of all the possible errors.. and now even thought theres no errors.. its not printing anything

Comment: Would you have any idea as to why this isnt working ? :(

Comment: You should probably at least put a message in that `die()` statement that indicates that it's dying there, otherwise your code might do the exact thing its doing right now and die for no apparent reason without producing any useful information at all. Also, make sure `error_reporting` is on, and **check your function returns**.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems here. First, this...

> $user_id = is_numeric($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : die();

is just terrible. I also don't see a `session_start()` (which may be the actual cause of your problems). Go with something like

```
session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['user_id']))) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid user id in session');
}
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Now for your result set iteration...

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($stmt as $row) { // this is possible because PDOStatement implements Traversable
    echo $row['title'];
}
```